# Show Image and test in some style

Tags: android, android-styles

In my app Splash screen is there in which one background, one image, one text view and some button is there.
I want when screen get launch then it show only background image only after half second image and after half second text view and in last after half second all the button.

All these things working. Only I want Image come slowly slowly, text view come slowly slowly and in last all the button come slowly slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use animation for that and set the duration for that animation according to your requirement. You can also set the animation one after other. For example:

```
TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 100);
//here you can set the duration    for slow animation.
  trans.setDuration(250);
  trans.setInterpolator(new        AccelerateInterpolator(1.0f));
someView.startAnimation(trans);
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, thanks user3541465, one more request...
I have seen in some app that image or text come slowly with some dot- dot.
Complete image appears with dot-dot with in 2 or 3 second. How I will achieve this?

Comment: I didn't get your query, whats the dot-dot thing, can you post any sample image for better explanation.

Comment: suppose image is made of 200*200 pixels and we need to display image in 5 second then it starts with some pixels and it will complete in 5 second

Comment: For that you can use fading animation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74543/discussion-between-user3541465-and-vinit-vikash).

Answer (score 2):

You need to animate your views. For transparency, you'll need to setup an `anim` xml file that animates a view's `<alpha>` property. This has the advantage of reusing the same xml file for all of your image and text views.

Your xml, say `/res/anim/show_after_delay.xml`, would look like

```
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha = "0.0"
    android:toAlpha = "1.0"
    android:duration = 1000 />
```

Then you can apply this animation on a view as

```
ImageView myImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImg);
Animation showAfterDelay = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.show_after_delay);
myImg.startAnimation(showAfterDelay);
```